# GUILayout.FlexibleSpace() don't work in unity 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

[Unity Editor 2019]

The

```
class GUILayout.FlexibleSpace()
```

is not working in the Unity 2019.2.4, does anyone know why?

How i fix it?

Comment: According to the documentaion it is included and no reason for it not to work unless you have a mistake in your use of it. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.FlexibleSpace.html

Comment: I am using it inside OnInspectorGUI() in the version Unity2018 worked good but's in the version 2019 this is not work

The solution for me was to use

GUILayout.Space (int)
instead in
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace()

Comment: might be related to the [new UI](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/07/30/heres-whats-in-the-brand-new-unity-2019-2/). For 2019.2 they made a complete new UI .. also for the editor itself ... a lot of Editor scripting might not work anymore with this newer versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use

```
GUILayout.Space (int);
```

instead in

```
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace()
```